# Multi-threaded Execution in Excel Power Query

Tags: multithreading, powerquery

I'm trying to get a handle on power query's parallel processing characteristics, but haven't found any documentation.

It seems queries normally run in the "Microsoft.Mashup.Container.NetFX40.exe" that appears in task manager's process list. I've (unwittingly) built some that appear to run Multi-threaded as multiple processes with that same name run in parallel for a while.

However, I don't understand what has caused a large and complex query I created to run almost entirely within the EXCEL.EXE process instead, using a single CPU core, when most of the query is about accessing a list of server sources, processing each independently, and only combining them at the end.

Is any reading available?

Comment: I'm not sure what tools you're using to query Excel, but I believe that Excel uses a single-threaded apartment model and, therefore, doesn't allow any multi-threaded queries.

Comment: Odd, I thought that with M being a functional paradigm language and as many Microsoft. Mashup.Container.NetFX40.exe processes as my computer has cores, that M was Multi-threaded. Doesn't M run concurrently in these other processes and then pass the result back to Excel? My problem is just about finding how to avoid whatever triggers single-threading as long as possible.

Comment: @alazyworkaholic Is each of your datasources appear as a separate query? E.g., Query1 = `Sql.Database() //db="db1", item = Sales`, Query2 = `Sql.Database() //db = "db1", item = "Orders"`, Query3 = `Sql.Database() //db = "db1", item = "OrderItems"`, etc. And then unsing all data sources in final QueryN ~= `Table.Combine(Query1, Query2, Query3) //something like that`?

Comment: Do you have "allow data preview to download in the background" enabled? You can check by going to the Options dialog, then Current Workbook | Data Load, then checking the "Allow data preview to download in the background" checkbox. If it's checked, and you uncheck it, do you see less CPU usage?